# Is there a way to get a list of all the places where a variable is touched in a project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2003

I am trying to figure out where a variable is being assigned a for-it nosensical value. I 
know I can select "Find Usages" from the context menu, and get a list of the places 
where it is referenced within its own unit, such as:

```
string name;
. . .
name = "Bla";
```

...but in cases where it is referenced outside the class, such as:

```
WorkFiles wrkFile = new WorkFiles();
wrkFile.name = Bla;
```

...Find Usages does not help out. Is there a way to see all the places a variable is touched within a project?

### UPDATE

The only place the var is being assigned to in the class of which it is a member is this:

```
name = aname.Remove(0, 3);
```

...All other places where "Find Usages" found "name" are as parameters to SQL statements; but at one point it has a value such as the full value entered in an unrelated text box. So it has to be being assigned to elsewhere. Or the name "name" is causing something untoward to occur...

Selecting "Go to Reference" from the context menu takes me to the line of code shown above.

### UPDATE 2

This looks promising:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fb5badda-4ea3-4314-a723-a1975cbdabb4

Comment: What does "Find usages" do wrong?

Comment: "Find usages" should also work for usages outside the class... are you sure that name isn't a local variable in your first example?

Comment: R# has a Find Usages Advanced too, but this is a 14-day free trial

Comment: You're looking for `RightClick->FindAllReferences` shortcut `Shift+F12`

Comment: I have R#; I'll try that, too.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Find Sausages does not find anything outside of the class where the variable is declared. Perhaps because there are no such instances, but so far that doesn't make sense...

Comment: a local variable inside a method is scoped within that method and cannot be referenced outside the class. What you're asking for makes no sense.

Comment: @HighCore: string name is not marked as private, and is declared right away after the class: public class WorkFiles
 {
  string name;

Comment: @ClayShannon class fields without explicit access modifier are by default `private`.

Comment: FindUsage returns the usages in the whole solution, not only the current class. And your string name is not marked explicitly private, but it's private implicitly unless you write public or protected.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault that's what I'm talking about.

Comment: IIRC, default access in C# should is internal. So anything in his class's own assembly can access his class's string variable.

Comment: Ever more curious; first of all, I would never name a var "name" because of the potential for clashes/collisions; maybe that is part of the problem?

Comment: @StarPilot wrong. That applies for classes, structs and interfaces. For class members default is `private`. Check [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx)

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault, private access is the default for C++. He marked this as C#. That uses internal as its default.

Comment: @StarPilot wrong again.

Comment: @StarPilot you don't remember correctly. Internal is for `namespace members` not for `Type members`. for type members it is private

Comment: @StarPilot It's private. [Members of: Class. Default member accessibility:Private](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx)

Comment: Find Sausages Advanced found the same things; then again, this is an ancient version of everything I'm using (VS2003, .NET 1.1, R# whatever).

Comment: @HighCore thanks! I was thinking of the top level. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Are you using reflection or data-binding anywhere?

Comment: Have you done a clean and rebuild cycle, exiting and restarting VS after? I have found that the references system in VS sometimes would lose references if there were failed builds. I have never had the built in tool fail to find legitimate references in my code otherwise (although third party DLLs you reference and use in databinding, for example, might do strange things they don't document.)

Comment: Rename the variable / field / property (without using refactoring tools) and see what the compiler says...

Comment: And sometimes the simplest things are best. Plus one to Roger's suggestion: if it compiles with a random name (change both locations you know about, definition and use), you don't have any direct references.

Comment: Next time, please admit you're running VS2003.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Sorry about that, I'm going back forth between projects in VS2003, VS2010, and VS2012 (at home) and made a boo-boo.